# What is a good UV mapping library writing in C++?

Tags: c++, blender, uv-mapping

I am currently scripting Blender right now but it's excruciatingly slow for large models.

Comment: depends, what kind of models and textures are you working with?

Comment: Building 3D models of rooms from Kinect data. For ex: http://www.kinectathome.com/models/4e729d3c-b84e-4153-a825-ad76116bcb72/

This is a small model but I meant the larger ones.

Comment: You might get more responses at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/) and [freeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) when building something from scratch. However, if you want to use an existing framework to save time, I recommend [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/). There's also a converter written for Ogre to convert models from blender called [blender2Ogre](http://code.google.com/p/blender2ogre/). However, it's kindof in the beta stages. You will also find [tutorials](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Blender%20to%20Ogre) on the Ogre wiki.